# How to assign empty value to NSData not NULL value?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdata

How to assign empty value to an NSData not NULL value ?

I didn't want to assign null nor nil. I wanted empty value not like the code below.

```
NSData* variable = NULL; // not even assigning to nil
NSData* variable = nil;
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
NSData *variable = [[NSData alloc] init];
// don't forget to release if not using ARC.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] init];
```